# Find number of subset that satisfy these two conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

```
def findNumber(N,A,B):
    return count
```

Count is total number of subsets of array - [1,2,3,...,N] satisfying these Conditions:

**1. All subsets should be contiguous.**

**2. No subset should contain A[i] and B[i] (order doesn't matter).**

Example

N = 3, A=[2,1,3], B=[3,3,1]

All subsets = [1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]

Invalid subsets = [2,3] because A[0] and B[0] are in it.  [1,2,3] because it contains A[1],B[1] and A[2],B[2]

so count will be 4.

I was able to figure out that total number of contiguous subsets will be **N(N+1)/2** But i got stuck on how to satisfy condition 2.

I tried explaining it as best as i could please ask for clarification if needed.

**EDIT**

```
def findallvalid(n,a,b):
    for w in range(1, n+1):
        for i in range(n-w+1):
            if not((a[0],b[0]) in (i+1,i+w+1)):
                yield range(i+1,i+w+1)
```

I tried this code but i don't know how to iterate over all values of a and b without making this very slow. It's already to slow on n>10^2.

1<=n<=10^5
1<=len(A)<=10^6

Comment: Please update the question with the code you already have.

Comment: When you say "not subset should contain `A[i]` and `B[i]`", do you mean a subset is invlid only and only if `A[i]` *and* `B[i]` are in that subset, for the same `i`?

Comment: @00 yes that's the only condition except subsets being contiguous.

Comment: @CosminStaicu i added my code to the question.

Comment: What is the maximum or typical length of A and B?

Comment: You'll find that generating the subsets for N = 100000 alone is very _slow_, without even taking A and B into consideration, so if already N = 101 is too _slow_ for you, you are asking for a miracle - unless A and B would rule out the majority of subsets.

Comment: Is this a question from a competitive programming website, if yes
I would love to have a link to the problem, to read the full description

Comment: @Armali I've added length of A and B, I'm interested in how to approach this problem without generating subsets, for example I found total contiguous subsets will be n(n+1)/2 I just want to know how to know number of subsets to rule out.

Comment: @RadwanAbu-Odeh Because this is a skill test, the link will work only for my account. Here's a link to the screenshot i took of the problem. [link](https://imgur.com/a/luYZhmb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm interested in how to approach this problem without generating subsets, for example I found total contiguous subsets will be n(n+1)/2 I just want to know how to know number of subsets to rule out.

That gave me an idea - indeed it is quite simple to compute the number of subsets ruled out by a single pair (A[i], B[i]). A little more challenging it is to do for multiple pairs, since the excluded subsets can overlap, so just subtracting a number for each pair won't work. What works is to have a set of the numbers or indexes of all N(N+1)/2 subsets, and remove the indexes of the excluded subsets from it; at the end, the cardinality of the reduced index set is the wanted number of remaining subsets.

```
def findNumber(N, A, B):
    count = N*(N+1)//2
    powerset = set(range(count))    # set of enumeration of possible intervals
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        if a > b: a, b = b, a       # let a be the lower number
        # when a and b are in a subset, they form a sub-subset of length "span"
        span = (b-a)+1
        start = 0       # index where the invervals of current length w begin
        for w in range(1, N+1):     # for all interval lengths w
            if span <= w:           # if a and b can be in interval of length w
                first = 0 if b <= w else b-w    # index of first containment
                last = a                        # index of last containment
                # remove the intervals containing a and b from the enumeration
                powerset -= set(range(start+first, start+last))
            start += N+1-w          # compute start index of next length w
    return len(powerset)            # number of remaining intervals
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some small modification to your code,
this code is really slow, because it is iterating over the entire list which can be made of 10^5 items, and doing some nested operation which will make the complexity skyrocket up to 10^10, which is really slow

```
from collections import defaultdict

def findallvalid(N,A,B):
  a_in = defaultdict(list)
  b_in = defaultdict(list)

  for idx, a in enumerate(A):
    a_in[a].append(idx)
  for idx, b in enumerate(B):
    b_in[b].append(idx)

  def diff_elem_index(subset):
    indecies = []
    for elem in subset:
      indecies.extend(a_in[elem])
      indecies.extend(b_in[elem])
    return len(set(indecies)) == len(indecies)

  for set_window in range(1, N+1):
      for start_idx in range(N - set_window + 1):
        sett = list(range(start_idx+1,start_idx + set_window + 1))
        if diff_elem_index(sett):
          yield sett
```

---

My closest assumption, since the code only needs to return the count of items
it can be solved mathematically

All contagious permutations of a N-size list is `(N*(N+1))/2 + 1`
after that you need to deduct the count of possible permutations that doesn't comply with the second condition, which can be figured out from list `A` and `B`

I think calculating the count excluded permutations from list `A` and `B`, will be much more efficient than going through all permutations from 1 to N.

Comment: I tried your solution, and modified it, so it only returns the count. But still it's exceeding the time limit of 10 seconds. can explain how can i find numbers of sets to be excluded.